# Rails' ActiveRecord serialize :attr method gives "Missing Class or module error"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization, activerecord

I'm trying to serialize a simple attribute in an ActiveRecord model, and Rails 2.3.4 doesn't like it.

```
class Shopper
  serialize :tags
end

>> a = Shopper.new
=> <#Shopper...>

>>a.tags = ['aoeu','stnh']
=> ['aoeu','snth']

>> a.save
=> TypeError: class or module required
```

anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Arf...I thought I could serialize two attributes in one go, but that's not the case:

```
serialize :tags, :garments   # this is wrong
```

The second argument is supposed to be the class of the serialized object, so  I have to do this:

```
serialize :tags
serialize :garments
```

bumsicle.

Comment: Thanks for this! Would have caused much headache if you hadn't posted. :)

Comment: can I upvote the word "bumsicle" alone? That is my new word for the week.